# Insert a slash (/) at the end of an element before the > using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

i'm trying to add a slash at the end of a meta tag before the > using javascript. The meta tag is created using `document.createElement('meta')`

This is my code:

```js
var link = document.createElement('meta');
link.name = "my:url";
link.content = "Content should be displayed";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

What comes out is this:

```
<meta name="my:url" content="Content should be displayed">
```

What i want it to come out as:

```
<meta name="my:url" content="Content should be displayed"/>
```

Would this be possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first question would be: why?

Comment: Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags require a slash @ChrisG

Comment: How do you figure? Their example code does have a slash at the end, but that's not required by either the HTML5 standard or so that open graph tags work...?

Comment: Are you running the Javascript on the server? If not that is your problem. Facebook doesn't execute Javascript.